# get some substring from readline() in python with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I use tcpdump to sniff my network packet and I want to get some info out of the stored file. My file have 2 separated lines but they repeated many times.

```
23:30:43.170344 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55731, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 443)

192.168.98.138.49341 > 201.20.49.239.80: Flags [P.], seq 562034569:562034972, ack 364925832, win 5840, length 403
```

I want to get **timestamp**(23:30:43.170344) and **id**(id 55731) and **offset**(23:30:43.170344) from first line(all line like this on my file). and store in a different list.

And get 2 **separated ip** (192.168.98.138.49341 and 201.20.49.239.80) and **seq** (seq 562034569:562034972) and **ack**(ack 364925832) from the second (all line like this on my file) line and store in a different list.

If I can do this with a regular expression it would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the first portion, to get timestamp, id and offset.**

I am sure this is a crude regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> l = '23:30:43.170344 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55731, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 443)'
>>> k = re.compile(r'^([0-9:]+\.[0-9]+) IP \(.* id ([0-9]+), offset ([0-9]+).*\)')
>>> x = k.match(l)
>>> x.groups()
('23:30:43.170344', '55731', '0')
>>> x.groups()[0]
'23:30:43.170344'
>>> x.groups()[1]
'55731'
>>> x.groups()[2]
'0'
>>>
```

For the second part:

```
>>> l = '192.168.98.138.49341 > 201.20.49.239.80: Flags [P.], seq 562034569:562034972, ack 364925832, win 5840, length 403'
>>> k = re.compile(r'^([0-9.]+) > ([0-9.]+): .* seq ([0-9:]+), ack ([0-9]+).*')
>>> x = k.match(l)
>>> for y in x.groups(): print y
... 
192.168.98.138.49341
201.20.49.239.80
562034569:562034972
364925832
```

For a read up on re module:

- http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/re/

Comment: tanx for your answer but how can tell python to do this just for my odd or even line. and also I prefere get like (id 55731) and (offset 0) and how can I write regular expression for second line?

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: Just match every line with the compiled regex objects. If the line does not matches then it returns none else it returns a match object from which information can be extracted.